# How do I "Correctly" include a Python.h header in my C++ program in VSCODE?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-code, arduino, platformio

My Environment:

1- MacOs catalina.

2- VScode "Visual Studio Code"

3- PlatformIO extension (for Arduino Development in C/C++) mainly C++

4- Python3 and Python2 are both installed on my mac.

The Problem:

I was trying to embed a python application called "sr1.py" into my C++ application but I'm getting this error when hovering on the `#inclde <python.h>` squiggly red line:

> #include errors detected. Please update your includePath.
> Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit
> (/Users/ImCodeName7/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/speech_recognision/src/main.cpp).C/C++(1696)
> cannot open source file "python.h"C/C++(1696)

CODE:

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <python.h>


int main()
{
    char filename[] = "sr1.py";
    FILE* fp;

    Py_Initialize();

    fp = _Py_fopen(filename, "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Please note I am still learning how to configure my environment so please bear with me. Thank you!

Edit1:
The source file is mainly written in C++ (Or known as Arduino C actually!)

Comment: For a start, decide for one language, not both C and C++.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It is C++, Actually the file has an extension of .cpp

Comment: Then please read the descriptions of the tags that you applied to this question and what you wrote in the question and title. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: **Which documentation did you read?** Consider reading the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Take inspiration from the source code of [Python](http://python.org) and of [Clang analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/). If you code in C++, read [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) - a draft C++ standard.  Consider using [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) or [Clang analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is simply a result of not including the proper path in the `c_cpp_properties.json` file.

If you know the path where `python` is located all you need to do is add the following to your [c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) file:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "FOO",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/PATH/TO/DIR/CONTAINING-Python.h",
                // --- E.g. ---
                "/usr/include/python3.9/Python.h",
                // Or
                "/usr/include/python3.9"
            ],

        }
    ],
}
```

---

If you don't, then you have to do some digging. For other *NIX systems the process should be similar, for ubuntu see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261759/python-h-file-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04-even-after-installing-python-dev) post.

For example, if you use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) or [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).

`Python.h` should be located in:

> ../foo/<ENV_NAME>/include/pythonX.Y

> So you would change `"/PATH/TO/DIR/CONTAINING/Python.h"` to `"../foo/<ENV_NAME>/include/pythonX.Y"`

To find the file:

> Find the folder where the python executable is located.
>
> > `which python` (or which python2 / python3)
>
> This should produce a file path that looks something like this:
>
> > `../foo/<ENV_NAME>/bin/python`
>
> Change your current working directory to `<ENV_NAME>`
>
> > `cd ../foo/<ENV_NAME>`
>
> In `<ENV_NAME>` there should be an `include` directory and in the
> `include` directory there should be another directory named
> `pythonX.Y`. This is the directory where `Python.h` is found.

E.g.

```bash
ENV_NAME/
├─ bin/
├─ include/
│  ├─ python3.9/
│  │  ├─ Python.h
│  │  ├─ ...
├─ lib/
├─ share/
├─ var/
├─ .../
```

---

**On mac, no conda with homebrew**

A little more tricky and requires a little more digging. In my case I found it located at

> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9

---

For windows (without any package managers) the default location is:

> C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PythonXY\include

However, if it is not there, it [should be](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) located at one of the following locations:

1. `%ProgramFiles%\Python X.Y`
2. `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Python X.Y`
3. `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\PythonXY`
4. `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\PythonXY-32`
5. `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\PythonXY-64`